# Sending FormData to Node server - cannot get it in x-www-form-urlencoded format

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to send data from a form, send it to the server which will then make a request to an external API. After the server retrieves that data, the server will send it to the browser to be manipulated and displayed. The REST API I'm calling requires the data to be in x-www-form-urlencoded format. However, the form keeps sending in multipart/form-data format.

From what I've been reading, I can't use the HTML form to send the data because I am requesting data back from the server and need to be able to handle the response.

HTML:

```
    <form id="myForm" action="/" method="POST" enctype="application/x-www-form-urlencoded">
      <input type="text" placeholder="URL to parse" name="url"></input>
      <input type="submit" value="Submit"></input>
    </form>
```

Client-side JS:

```
const form = document.forms['myForm'];

form.addEventListener('submit', event => {
  event.preventDefault();
  var data = new FormData(form),
      thisMethod = form.getAttribute('method'),
      thisAction = form.getAttribute('action'),
      url = data.get('url');

  data.append('url', url);

  fetch(thisAction, {
    method: thisMethod,
    headers: {
      "Content-Type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"
    },
    body: data
  }).then(res => console.log(res)).catch(e => console.log(e));
});
```

Anyone have any idea what the issue is? When I use Postman and use x-www-form-urlencoded format, everything works perfectly.

Comment: Based on the [specification](https://fetch.spec.whatwg.org/#body-mixin) the used serializer will be defined by the type of the body. `FormData` -> `multipart/form-data` and `URLSearchParams` -> `application/x-www-form-urlencoded`

Comment: try `var data =  new URLSearchParams(form)` instead